# Trimming white spaces/converting iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator, compiler-errors

I wanted to write two one-line functions which will trim white spaces from left and right side of a string. Left side weren't problem:

```
void trimLeft(string &s) {
  s.erase(s.begin(), find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), (int (*)(int))isgraph));
}
```

But when I tried something similar for right side:

```
void trimRight(string &s) {
  s.erase(find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), (int (*)(int))isgraph), s.end());
}
```

I had some compiler errors. The problem is that I must convert reverse_iterator (which is returned by find_if) to normal iterator. How to do this?

Comment: There is always `trim` at Boost.StringAlgorithm

Comment: It's for school project, and I can't use Boost.

Comment: Why are you casting `isgraph`?

Comment: because without casting I have compiler error. I don't know why, so I just used casting.

Comment: You should rewrite `isgraph` to have the signature `bool isgraph(char)`.

Comment: Strings are made up of `char`s (not `int`s), predicates return `true` or `false` (not `int`s). So if you want `isgraph` to be a predicate on elements of strings then this provides better (implicit) documentation about the possible arguments and return values.

Comment: The reason that you are getting a compiler error is that the `C++` standard library includes two functions with the name `isgraph`. There is `int isgraph(int c)` in `<cctype>`, and `template <class charT> bool isgraph(charT c, const locale& loc)` in `<locale>`.
The cast is needed to make the compiler know that you are referring to the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `base()` member function to recover the underlying iterator from its reverse_iterator.

```
void trimRight(string &s) {
  s.erase(find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), (int (*)(int))isgraph).base(), s.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, it seems like string::erase should take reverse_iterators just fine.  The problem is that you're mixing reverse and forward iterators.  So try

```
void trimRight(string &s) {
  s.erase(s.rbegin(), find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), (int (*)(int))isgraph));
}
```

Edit: Nope.

Comment: I don't work for me. Compiler error. no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::erase(std...

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::erase(std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)’...

Comment: .../usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/bits/basic_string.h:1131: note: candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/bits/basic_string.h:1147: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> > std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> >) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]

Comment: ...c/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/bits/basic_string.h:1167: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> > std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> >) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]

Comment: Ok, I guess erase doesn't take reverse_iterators, sorry,

Answer (score 0):

Use boost::trim?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2895820